# ADF copy activity and data flow behaving differently when writing data to multi lookup field in Dynamics 365

Tags: azure, dynamics-365, azure-data-factory

I am trying to import data from a CSV file into a Dynamics 365 Account table. As I need to do some transformations I am using a dataflow rather than a basic copy activity.

I was having difficulties getting it to work using a dataflow for writing to a multi lookup field so I tried using a copy activity to see if that worked using the exact same source,sink and mappings. I was able to import the
data successfully with the copy activity. I'm confused as to why the data flow does not work using the same source,sink and mappings. Below are screenshots of the various elements I set up and configured. Would appreciate any suggestions to get the dataflow working.

I'm using a cut down version of what will ultimately be my source CSV file. This is just so I can concentrate on getting the writing to the lookup field working.

## Source CSV file

[image]

## Copy Activity Source

[image]

## Copy Activity Sink

[image]

## Dynamics 365 Sink

[image]

## Dataflow Source

[image]

## Dataflow Sink

[image]

## Copy Activity Mapping

[image]

## Dataflow Mapping

[image]

## Copy Activity Success

[image]

## Dataflow Failure

[image]

## Dataflow Error

[image]

Details
{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: DF-REST_001 - Rest - Error response received from the server (url:https://##############v9.0/accounts,request body: Some({"accountid":"8b0257ea-de19-4aaa-9945-############","name":"A User","ownerid":"7d64133b-daa8-eb11-9442-############","ownerid@EntityReference":"systemuser"}), request method: POST, status code: 400), response body: Some({"error":{"code":"0x0","message":"An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the property 'ownerid'; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected.\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ValidateExpandedNestedResourceInfoPropertyValue(IJsonReader jsonReader, Nullable1 isCollection, String propertyName, IEdmTypeReference typeReference)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeserializ","Details":"com.microsoft.dataflow.Issues: DF-REST_001 - Rest - Error response received from the server (url:https://dev-gc.crm11.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts,request body: Some({"accountid":"8b0257ea-de19-4aaa-9945-############","name":"A User","ownerid":"7d64133b-daa8-eb11-9442-############","ownerid@EntityReference":"systemuser"}), request method: POST, status code: 400), response body: Some({"error":{"code":"0x0","message":"An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the property 'ownerid'; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected.\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ValidateExpandedNestedResourceInfoPropertyValue(IJsonReader jsonReader, Nullable1 isCollection, String propertyName, IEdmTypeReference typeReference)\r\n at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightResourceDeser"}

Comment: did this ever work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I am running into a same wall,
but a temporary solution here is to sink the dataflow output to a Csv/or similar file into ADLS and then use a Copy activity to extract those files and Upsert it into the Dynamics.

Other references: https://vishalgrade.com/2020/10/01/how-to-populate-multi-lookup-attribute-in-ce-using-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Yes this is what I have been doing as an interim solution. Would be nice to know if it can be done with dataflow to avoid then need of a staging area though. :)

Answer (score 0):

here's an easier way to insert/update lookup fields:

1. in the sink mapping, you set the lookup's destination column with schema name (which is usually PascalCased), and append @odata.bind so that the column name would look like xx_InstrumentId@odata.bind

[image]

2. the value you're passing to the column is "/xx_orders(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx)" - ensure the entity name is PLURAL and lowercase!
3. to generate this value, you can use the "Derived Column" block, putting "/xx_orders(" + your_instrument_id + ")" into the expression field.
   [image]

[image]